# Two-state Markov Chains

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

If I have a two-state Markov chian $V(t)$ with transition probabilities:

$P_{00}(t)=(1-\pi) + \pi e^{-\tau t}$

$P_{01}(t)= \pi - \pi e^{-\tau t}$

$P_{10}(t)=(1-\pi) - (1-\pi)e^{-\tau t}$

$P_{11}(t)= \pi + (1-\pi)e^{-\tau t}$

The initial distribution is $(1-\pi,\pi)$ and assuming $Pr(V(0)=0)=1- \pi$ and $Pr(V(0)=1)=\pi$

I'm trying to figure out how to show that $Pr(V(t)=1)=\pi$ for all t>0.  My thinking is that I need to use the fact that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}P_{01}(t)$$=$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}P_{11}(t)$$= $\pi$

Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: So you have written $e^{Lt}$, where $L$ is the generator of this continuous time process? If so then the rest of the problem is calculating $L$ and checking $\pi L = 0$, I think. Just the limit will do you no good, because you need to show that the distribution is constant over all time.

Comment: Limits when $t\to\infty$ can say nothing about the distribution of $V(t)$ for fixed $t$. Rather use the Bayes formula $$P(V(t)=1)=P(V(0)=1)P_{11}(t)+P(V(0)=0)P_{01}(t).$$

Comment: thank you! I appreciate it